# Translation of one line into several lines

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I get table 2 from table 1?

[image: table1]

[image: table2]

The main drawback of the first table is that numbers can be separated by commas or spaces, or non-numeric characters. As in the example.

Comment: Can you add that exact data as text as opposed to an image? just copy it raw from excel and paste > format as code. see [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for extract numbers to list and then [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df1 = df.assign(A = df['A'].str.findall('\d+')).explode('A').reset_index(drop=True)
```

For oldiest pandas version is possible use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
c = df.columns
s = df.pop('A').str.extractall('(\d+)')[0].reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('A')

df = df.join(s).reindex(c, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got the error      AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @asymon - is possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: @asymon - Added solution for oldier pandas versions

Comment: My God, you are a wizard. There were problems with the update. Thank!